# Excel 2010 VBA formula with variable messing up

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have this code:

```
LastLine = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastLine = "C" & LastLine
Range(LastLine).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R4C3:R[-1]C)"
Range("E13").FormulaR1C1 = "=if(R12C5 - " & LastLine & " <> 0,R12C5 - " & LastLine & ","""")"
```

everything works expect for the formula the outcome for that is

"=IF($E$12 - $Z:$Z <> 0,$E$12 - $Z:$Z,"")"

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? also when I try

```
LastLine = Range(LastLine).address
```

It gives me an error

Comment: Try `LastLine = "C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row` instead

Comment: What do you expect the formula to be?

Comment: the formula should be "=IF($E$12 - C# <> 0,$E$12 - C#,"")" where it finds the last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using R1C1 notation you have to translate `CsomeRow` to `RsomeRowC3`

```
Range("E13").FormulaR1C1 = "=if(R12C5 - R" & LastLine & "C3 <> 0,R12C5 - R" & LastLine & "C3,"""")"
```

Comment: I was just think I could Use the normal address of C26 forgot I should put it in the R26C3 Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The variable LastLine is not typed and you change its type throughout your code. First, it is a number (the number of the row), then you assign it text, the letter C combined with the row number, for example "C3". Next you use that in an R1C1 reference, where C3 means Column 3, so the row number from the first LastLine assignment will end up as the column in the formula.

Your code would be cleaner if your variables were dimmed to specific types and you would not mix A1 notation with R1C1.

```
Sub test()
Dim LastLine As Long
Dim LastLineCell As String

LastLine = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastLineCell = "C" & LastLine
Range(LastLineCell).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R4C3:R[-1]C)"
Range("E13").FormulaR1C1 = "=if(R12C5 - R" & LastLine & "C26 <> 0,R12C5 - R" & LastLine & "C26,"""")"
End Sub
```